# Search and edit .txt fstream files according to ID/ Registration

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to search a specific ID/ registration from a .txt and display the corresponding info accordingly. In this case I want to display the pricing according to the corresponding registration number which should be entered.

Reading and writing files is not the issue for me. There is a lot of info on the web in regards with reading and writing, but not much on searching and displaying according to the ID/ registration.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    double cost;
    string reg;

    ifstream in_stream;
    ofstream out_stream;

    char registration[10]; 

    //Open file
    in_stream.open("Fines.dat");

    //Error if opening fails
    if (in_stream.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file could not open. " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    //Open out stream file
    out_stream.open("OutStandingFines.dat");

    //Error if opening fails
    if (out_stream.fail())
    {
        cout << "Output file opening failed.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    //Display original .dat file
    cout <<"Original .dat File" << endl;
    if(in_stream.is_open())
    {
        while(in_stream >> reg >> cost)
        {       
                cout << reg <<" " << cost << '\n';

        }
        in_stream.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"File is not open: " << endl;
    }



/////////////My problem is from here//////////////////////////

    //Enter the registration number you wish to search
    cout << "Please enter registration number: " << endl;
    cin >>registration;



//I must display all cost values that have the same registration number???????? I need help with this
/*
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {


                if( reg == registration)
                {   

                    cout << fixed << setw(2)<< setprecision(2) <<"R " << cost << '\n';
                    out_stream << fixed << setw(2)<< setprecision(2) << "R "<< cost << endl; //send back to .dat
                }


    }

*/




    in_stream.close();
    out_stream.close();

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Just read the file exactly the same way you did higher up in the code (with the if-statement added)? You might also want to consider loading your data into memory or using some sort of database, but getting into that is a bit beyond the scope of a comment / answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to get the output. The problem I have now is to display all the values with the same registration/ ID.

For some reason only the last row in the fstream .txt gets displayed when I enter "ABC123".

### The input .txt contains the following info.

```
ABC123 400
DEC234 340
ABC123 500
GED345 600
ABC123 240
GEE600 120
GED345 230
GEE600 470
ABC123 120
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string line;
    double cost;
    string reg;

    ifstream in_stream;
    ofstream out_stream;

    string registration; 


    in_stream.open("Fines.dat");

    if (in_stream.fail())
    {
        cout << "Input file could not open. " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    out_stream.open("OutStandingFines.dat");
    if (out_stream.fail())
    {
        cout << "Output file opening failed.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    //Display original .dat file
    cout <<"Original .dat File" << endl;
    if(in_stream.is_open())
    {
        while(in_stream >> reg >> cost)
        {       
                cout << reg <<" " << cost << '\n';
        }

    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"File is not open: " << endl;
    }



    //Enter Registration here
    cout << "Please enter registration number: " << endl;
    cin >>registration;

    //compare and display all registration numbers that match
    cout <<"Fines: " << endl;
    if(out_stream.is_open())
    {

        while(reg == registration)
        {       


                cout << fixed << setw(2)<< setprecision(2) <<"R " << cost << '\n';
                out_stream << fixed << setw(2)<< setprecision(2) << "R "<< cost << endl; //send back to .dat

            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<"File is not open: " << endl;
    }



    in_stream.close();
    out_stream.close();

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```